# need to upload multiple images at once in the same column

Tags: java, sql

so as above i need to upload more the one image to my database and i'm using Jfilechooser to select my files 
my code works fine for only one image at a time and i have a blob column to save my images in it

the code for my sql query

```
try {

        PreparedStatement pst =null;
        ResultSet rst=(ResultSet) pst;

        Connection con=(Connection)    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/iqari", "root","");
        String sql="UPDATE first SET test = ? WHERE   id  = ?";
        pst=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
           int row = masterTable.getSelectedRow();

        Object d =   masterTable.getValueAt(row, 0);
        pst.setBytes(1,person_image);
        pst.setObject(2,d);
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "done");
    } catch (Exception e) {


        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

the code for attaching my image
EDITED

```
    JFileChooser chooser =new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

    for (File f : files) {
   filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
   try
   {
    File image2 = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image2);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    for(int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
       bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
     }

     person_image = bos.toByteArray();
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
  }
```

any help can be useful guys.

Comment: Do you know how to create threads?

Comment: no sorry i'm new to this, but any help can be appreciated

Comment: Try this tutorial about thread. I think this is what your looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: For more information. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JFileChooser to open multiple txt files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922152/jfilechooser-to-open-multiple-txt-files)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error when you're using `.getSelectedFiles()` is because it's returning an Array of objects, not a singular object. Try something like this;

Updated code, I cannot test this..

```
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

// instantiates an array of byte arrays of size files.length
byte[][] images = new byte[files.length][];
int numberOfImages = 0;
for (File f : files) {
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    try 
    {
        File image2 = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image2);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        for(int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
           bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }

        person_image = bos.toByteArray();

        // adds the byte array to your array & increases the numberOfImages
        images[numberOfImages++] = person_image;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

In your original SQL code change this part;

```
pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
int row = masterTable.getSelectedRow();

Object d = masterTable.getValueAt(row, 0);
pst.setBytes(1,person_image);
pst.setObject(2,d);
pst.execute();
```

To this;

```
for(byte[] imageAsByteArray : images) {
    pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

    int row = masterTable.getSelectedRow();
    Object d = masterTable.getValueAt(row, 0);

    pst.setBytes(1, imageAsByteArray);
    pst.setObject(2, d);
    pst.execute();
}
```

Comment: i'll try it now just a sec please.

Comment: seems like i can't use foreach because i'm working with netbeans jdk 6 
and it may need jdk 8

Comment: sorry my bad just a sec

Comment: no errors now but saves only one image and the other doesn't show in the column

Comment: could you edit your original post with the code you're using? I have a feeling you're only sending `person_image` once to your table

Comment: JFileChooser chooser =new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
 
        File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

for (File f : files) {
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();...... the rest is as your code exactly

Comment: that's fine, but what i'm saying is you are assigning your `byte` array to `person_image` what are you doing with that? are you sending it within the `for()` loop or out of it?

Comment: should i change any thing in my sql query?

Comment: see my edit soon, please read and understand it.. it's really hard to help you without knowing the structure of your application

Comment: alright thank you my friend 
i would give a +1 but i need more points

Comment: no problem, i'm happy to help..if i answered your question, just mark it as so...no need for a +1

Comment: :\ sorry nothing worked this time
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: a `NullPointerException` is generally easy to diagnose, have a look up about them. Debug your application, run through it step-by-step and see what's causing the issue.

Comment: catch clause gives a null now 
and no image was able to be saved